# How do you stop Minecraft from showing a black screen on a Nintendo Switch Lite?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, nintendo-switch-lite

I just went on my Nintendo Lite and I tapped Minecraft. I waited until Minecraft loaded for about 25 minutes then reset the console. But it still would not work, then I deleted it and added it back in.

How do you fix it? Why did it happen? How can you stop it from happening again? is it when you have too much storage?

Comment: What version are you running?

Comment: @DisplayNameNotFound if the game isn't loading, it's unlikely the OP will be able to determine the precise version; however, with that in mind, if they've deleted it and added it back, it's likely to be the *latest* version.

Comment: @Tacoタコス ok, Thanks!